# Как получать клавиши с раскладкой и capslock в PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

Нужно чтобы при нажатие любой клавиши можно было конвертировать в буквы если shift или какая сейчас раскладка, а также если capslock.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение: `event.unicode`
Он выдаёт символ с учётом shift, capslock и раскладки.